# I want to add missing dates in my SQL query

Tags: sql

I want to add missing dates in this query from `datec` column. I got a result of this query, but missing dates are not shown:

```
select 
    u.NAME, u.BADGENUMBER, 
    attendance.SENSORID, attendance.CHECKDate, 
    attendance.CheckIn ,attendance.CheckOut,
    cast(DATEDIFF(n, attendance.CheckIn, attendance.checkout) / 60 as varchar) + ':' + cast(DATEDIFF(n, attendance.CheckIn, attendance.checkout) % 60 as varchar) as Minutes
from 
    (select 
         temp.USERID, temp.SENSORID, temp.CHECKDate ,temp.CheckIn,
         case 
             when temp.COut = temp.CheckIn then null 
             when temp.CheckIn is null then null 
             else temp.COut 
         end as CheckOut
     from
         (select 
              c.USERID, c.SENSORID, convert(date, CHECKTIME) CHECKDate,
              -- (select temp.USERID, dateadd(day,1, CHECKTIME cinout where temp.USERID = c.USERID)) CHEC2
              (select min(CHECKTIME) from CHECKINOUT cinout 
               where cinout.USERID = c.USERID and cinout.SENSORID = c.SENSORID 
                 and cinout.CheckTime >= dateadd(hour, 6, convert(datetime, convert(date, c.CheckTime)))) CheckIn,
              (select max(CHECKTIME) from CHECKINOUT cinout 
               where cinout.USERID = c.USERID and cinout.SENSORID = c.SENSORID 
                 and cinout.CheckTime <= dateadd(hour, 29, convert(datetime, convert(date, c.CheckTime)))) COut
          from 
              CHECKINOUT c
          group by 
              c.USERID, c.SENSORID, convert(date, CHECKTIME), datename(DW, checktime)) temp
       ) attendance 
inner join  
     userinfo u on u.USERID = attendance.userid 
where 
     u.USERID = 77
```

Output:

```
Name  Badg  Sen CheckDate           CheckIn             Check Out           Minutes
Umair   77  1   2022-11-16  2022-11-16 09:41:25.000 2022-11-16 18:45:46.000 9:4
Umair   77  1   2022-11-21  2022-11-21 09:29:29.000 2022-11-21 19:00:33.000 9:31
Umair   77  1   2022-11-22  2022-11-22 09:25:19.000 2022-11-22 18:26:38.000 9:1
```

Comment: If you want column CheckDate to show all possible dates, even if there have not been any checkins and checkouts on a particular date, then I suggest you create a master calendar table that you left join to above query on CalendarDate = CheckDate.

Comment: How please send query